# Display Link Type in VSTS Query Results

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-workitem, tfs-query

How can I display the link type when using [Work Items and Direct Links](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/track/linking-attachments#list-items-based-on-linked-dependents)?

[image: query screenshot]

---

Seems like [Link Description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/track/linking-attachments#link-and-attachment-fields) is what I want but it is "not support in the query editor".

> Contains the work item type, ID, and title of the work item that is the target of the link. You can configure this field to appear as a column in a list of links on a work item form. (Not supported in query editor.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn’t such feature to display link type in UI Query Result. You can get it through REST API: [Run a stored query](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/wiql#run-a-stored-query)